# firebase.firestore() is not a function when trying to initialize Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to initialize Firebase Cloud Firestore, I ran into the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_firebase**.firestore is not a function

I installed firebase with `npm install firebase --save` previously.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import router from '../router';

const config = {
        apiKey: "a",
        authDomain: "a",
        databaseURL: "a",
        projectId: "a",
        storageBucket: "a",
        messagingSenderId: "a"
};
if(!firebase.apps.length){
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  let firestore = firebase.firestore();
}
```

Comment: Why have you saved the firebase dependency as a *dev* dependency?

Comment: Also, you need to make sure you have version 4.5.0 which is quite recent. Check your `package.json` and make sure you have the right version set

Comment: I uninstalled firebase and installed the new version with `npm install --save firebase@4.5.0` but it didn't change anything :/ @Phil

Comment: @eykjs What is the correct syntax for the second import?

Comment: `import 'firebase/firestore'` would be the right syntax.

Comment: Please read https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Comment: just import firebase directly: `import firebase from 'firebase'`

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I fixed it by importing multiple libraries: `firebase` and `firebase/firestore`. That's because the `firebase` core library does not include the firestore library.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Comment: Breaks on Android if you are using React Native. Seems to be fine on iOS :-/

Comment: This works perfectly as of February 2019. Thank you!! :)

Comment: Thank you! The second import statement  was what I was missing.

Comment: Im using vanilla js for building a simple chat app,I have included static URL in the head tag of the HTML file still I'm getting this error,pls help,thanks in advance

Answer (score 25):

If you are using the version the version 9 of firebase, then you need to use this instead:

```
// v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

Here is the link for the upgrade from version 8 to version 9 https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade.

> Keep in mind: the compat libraries are a temporary solution that will be removed completely in a future major SDK version (such as version 10 or version 11). Your ultimate goal is to remove compat code and keep only version 9 modular-style code in your app.

For the time being, you can utilize compat libraries but you should try to switch from compat to modular in the future.

Answer (score 19):

First, make sure you have latest version of firebase:

```
npm install firebase@4.12.0 --save
```

Next, add both firebase and firestore:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");
```

Initialize the firebase app:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
  authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
  projectId: '### CLOUD FIRESTORE PROJECT ID ###'
});

// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
var db = firebase.firestore();
```

source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0

Answer (score 15):

```
import { firebase } from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/firestore'
```

If you're using authentication as well

```
import '@firebase/auth';
```

Comment: For me I didn't require to add that import line but auth worked fine. Why is it only for firestore?

Answer (score 8):

I also struggled with this for a bit. what I did in the end was quite straightforward.

for versions 9 and higher, just do the following

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 
  authDomain: 
  projectId: 
  storageBucket: 
  messagingSenderId: 
  appId: 
};

// Initialize Firebase

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore;
const auth = firebaseApp.auth();


export { auth };
export default db; 

//cheers
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. 
Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your answer and explain 
how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 7):

Hope this helps to someone who faces the same problem when deploying an Angular app to Firestore.

In Angular 8 project, I had the same error when deploying to Firestore. 
I fixed it by adding another module **AngularFirestoreModule**.

App.module.ts is like this:

```
...
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore'; // << Note AngularFirestoreModule !!!
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
...

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
...
```

package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.2",
    "ajv": "^6.10.2",
    "bootstrap-scss": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^6.4.0",
...
```

UPDATE: 
When I deployed to some other hosting provider, this did not help. For this case, I added the original firebase library and it worked.

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase';
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case, the update (import { firestore } from 'firebase'; ) was not necessary.

Comment: man.  I was getting mad, adding AngularFirestoreModule  fixed my issue lol.  App worked without it locally but failed on Heroku.  Adding this was the fix... weird that the app worked without it a few months ago.  Guess an update I did required this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding AngularFirestoreModule to imports saved the day!

Answer (score 5):

You can create a separate component for initialization of firebase on you application using credentials.

> **firebase-context.js**

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "XXXX",
            authDomain: "XXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://XXXX-app-web.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "XXXX",
            storageBucket: "XXXX-app-web.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "XXXXXX",
            appId: "1:XXX:web:XXXX",
            measurementId: "G-XXXX"
        };

export default !firebase.apps.length 
  ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig).firestore()
  : firebase.app().firestore();
```

In case, you need to deal with database operation you don't need to call the initialize method each time, you can use common component method which is earlier created.

```js
import FirebaseContext from "./firebase-context";

export const getList = () => dispatch => {
    FirebaseContext.collection("Account")
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            // success code
        }).catch(err => {
            // error code
        });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If by any chance, your code is under witchcraft, and `import firebase/firestore` won't work, then include it directly:

```
import '@firebase/firestore/dist/esm/index';
```

If it's not there, then:

```
npm install @firebase/firestore
```

Comment: worked for me when i added: - npm install @firebase/firestore

Answer (score 3):

**The problem is not import the firestore**

firebase has many features.

You need to import or import from the CDN what you want to implement from the list below.

[image]
**The official reference** says to load firebase-firestore.js.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

if you want to use npm, here

```
npm install firebase@7.19.0 --save
```

**url is here**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0#set_up_your_development_environment

Answer (score 2):

I had same Error and tried to follow the official website but did not work.
Then I googled error and landed in this post.

I tried:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

However, it did not work for me but I added `/firebase` to the first line `import * as firebase from 'firebase/firebase';` and everything is working perfectly.

It also works with `require`:

```
const firebase = require("firebase/firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are updating from an earlier version of firebase and you are pulling your hair out about this issue, try
`const Firebase = require('firebase/firebase')` instead of `require('firebase/app')`

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that I've accidentally added `firebase-admin` alongside with the `firebase` package in my `package.json`. And `firebase-admin` took precedence so even after adding the imports as per the accepted answer I was still getting the same error.

Removing the redundant `firebase-admin` from the client app fixed the problem.

As a note, `firebase-admin` is intended for server side to operate in admin mode, while the `firebase` package is a client side library.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
```

> Just try this and see how it goes

Comment: let db = getFirestore();
export default db;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

To use firestore you need to add this link at the top of your html page.

```js
//After initializing firebase, in your main javascript page call...
var data = firebase.firestore();
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.1.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.3/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

Comment: The second script is to add firebase storage. You don't need it for the firestore.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Angular 8 (as of 4th January 2020):

1. Delete `package-lock.json` file
2. Run `npm install`
3. `import AngularFirestoreModule from @angular/fire/firestore`

Just need to import AngularFirestoreModule.

```js
// App.module.ts

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57593859/8020389

Comment: I gave my solution that worked specifically for angular 8 latest.

Comment: this helped me, but you also need to add AngularFirestoreModule to providers

Comment: Glad to know , it helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and like everything typed on typescript (it's the purpose, by the way), you can try:

```
import * as firebase from "nativescript-plugin-firebase";
import { User, firestore } from "nativescript-plugin-firebase";

import * as firebaseapp from "nativescript-plugin-firebase/app";
```

So you can do stuff like that:

```
firebase.getCurrentUser().then((user: User) => { /* something */ });

const mycollection : firestore.CollectionReference = firebaseapp.firestore().collection("mycollection");
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `node_modules` directory together with `package-lock.json` and then running `npm install` fixed it for me.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1880

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem, it was a bug. I was importing firestore from firebase (it was done automatically by the IDE...) when i should imported it from the .js file where i initialized firebase app.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the latest version of Angular 8.2.14, when I deployed to production, it cause this problem, so I add the following to `app.module.ts`

```
        imports: [
        ...,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
...
      ],
      providers: [AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreModule],
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [a useful comment in Github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2283) by alclimb

he mentioned about **firebase analytics won't work in Node.js**, because it meant to be used with a browser (this is mention in the official documentation)

Answer (score 0):

## **Enabling Firestore for Nativescript**

During plugin installation you'll be asked whether or not you use Firestore.

In case you're upgrading and you have the `firebase.nativescript.json` file in your project root, edit it and add: `"firestore": true`. Then run `rm -rf platforms && rm -rf node_modules && npm i`.

## **init / initializeApp**

By default Firestore on iOS and Android persists data locally for offline usage (web doesn't by default, and the regular Firebase DB doesn't either on any platform). If you don't like that awesome feature, you can pass `persist: false` to the [init function](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/f77d3ea25d70457e7428dafd9e15fa723d6ce6fc/README.md#init).

> Note that initializeApp is simply an alias for init to make the plugin compatible with the web API.

```
const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase/app");

firebase.initializeApp({
  persist: false
});
```

## **collection**

A 'collection' is at the root of any Firestore interaction. Data is stored as a 'document' inside a collection.

```
 const citiesCollection = firebase.firestore().collection("cities");
```

Source: [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/eddyverbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/HEAD/docs/FIRESTORE.md)

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla javascript on the client you need to include this script to make it work:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

as it's not included in the default snippet Google asks you to copy paste in your website.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

For 2022 readers, please check your `firebase` version.

The latest version now is 9.x. It is little different from mostly YouTube guides.

You need `firebase@8.x` to follow YouTube guides.

`npm uninstall firebase`

`npm install firebase@8.x`

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0#web-version-9_1

Comment: What is it about frameworks and libraries constantly changing things seemingly w/o purpose? Thank you for this! A very big help, and so frustrating firebase has entirely changed the way they handle things.

Answer (score 0):

For version 9 of firebase you can use

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue came from using the wrong import.  I create the firebase app elsewhere in my code with `initializeApp`.  This is a server side node.js app.  Firebase Admin cannot be used in the client anyway.

**Incorrect**

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

this.stripeAccountColl = admin.firestore(this.firebaseApp).collection("StripeAccount");
```

**Correct**

```
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';

this.stripeAccountColl = getFirestore(this.firebaseApp).collection("StripeAccount");
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the error was because I tried to import a file that used firebase.firestore() before I actually imported "firebase/firestore"

Answer (score -2):

To use `Firestore` cloud functions on Node.js you should use `admin.firestore()` instead of `admin.database()`. Also you should be sure that your module `firebase-admin` on `package.json` is up to `5.4.1` or above. Looking like something like:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {   
    "firebase-admin": "^5.4.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Question doesn't clarify that but it's regarding a client web app, not a Node server app.

Comment: I think your answer is incorrect if you consider usage for a web app built with vue / angular.
It works fine as a server app

Answer (score -2):

I think I've got it for folks using electron-webpack. Solution was from a post related to importing codemirror. https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack/issues/81

This worked for me.

```
// package.json
{
  //...
  "electronWebpack": {
    "whiteListedModules": [
      "firebase"
    ]   
  },
  //...
}
```

Answer (score -4):

simply the answer is just to link these script in your html file and check that the issue is resolved

script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"

script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js

gives upvote if it is helpful for fixing your problem

Comment: It looks like you might be misunderstanding. The question is asking about a node.js problem, so html tags won't be much help. Also, to keep the quality of your answers up, try refraining from asking for upvotes.