# Correct way to use initialize firestore in react-native expo app

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Have seen two different ways to initialize firestore in a react-native app and would like to know what the differences between the two are. The method shown *in the firestore docs* (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize) looks like

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

export fs = admin.firestore();
```

while the "firebase" way (as seen *in this expo post*: https://forums.expo.io/t/open-when-an-expo-firebase-firestore-platform/4126/29), which is the way I currently use and appears to work, looks like

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';//for using firestore functions, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50684682/8236733
import { firebaseConfig } from './firebase-credentials';//WARN: gitignored, exports object containing firebase (web)app credentials


// Initialize Firebase
// why in separate file? see https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1999 and https://ilikekillnerds.com/2018/02/solving-issue-firebase-app-named-default-already-exists/

// firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

try {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

    /*WARN:
    @firebase/firestore:, Firestore (5.0.4): 
    The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
    AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
    To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the
    following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:

    const firestore = firebase.firestore();
    const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
    firestore.settings(settings);

    With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read back as
    Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects. So you will also
    need to update code expecting a Date to instead expect a Timestamp. For example:

        // Old:
        const date = snapshot.get('created_at');
        // New:
        const timestamp = snapshot.get('created_at');
        const date = timestamp.toDate();

    Please audit all existing usages of Date when you enable the new behavior. In a
    future release, the behavior will change to the new behavior, so if you do not
    follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
    */
    const fsSettings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
    firebase.firestore().settings(fsSettings)
} catch (err) {
    // we skip the "already exists" message which is
    // not an actual error when we're hot-reloading
    if (!/already exists/.test(err.message)) {
        console.error('Firebase initialization error', err.stack)
    }
}

export const fs = firebase.firestore()
```

The post linked to is the only instance where I could find someone else doing this, but again it does work for me (can read and write to firestore).

Very new to using firebase/firestore and would like to use the more 'correct' method. Is there any difference between initializing firestore in the app in these separate ways?

Answer (score 1):

Import:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Then

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase

This is a JavaScript bridge to the native Firebase SDKs for both iOS and Android therefore Firebase will run on the native thread. 
It has a step-by-step instructions for react-native app integration with firebase. 
One important thing is that you have to consider about your react-native version and firebase sdk version.

Comment: I think this specific package only works for non-expo (or detached expo) react-native projects (based on the the platform-specific installation instructions https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/installation/initial-setup#Platform-Specific-Installation and this unmet expo feature request https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/adding-react-native-firebase-to-expo). Had seen this package earlier, but am using a react-native project created via `create-react-native-app`, so am using expo (which is why I was then looking between the two other options I had seen as shown in the question).

Answer (score 0):

They do the same things though? The first one simply does it by declaring and expo does it by declaring it inline. You can do it however you like, but both of them do the same things

Comment: "The first one simply does it by declaring and expo does it by declaring it inline". Can you add a bit more about you mean by this, I don't quite understand? (Also, should the first sentence end in a period)?