# TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.firestore is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently having issues with firebase. It was working before, but after someone tested it, it is not working anymore. The issues from the debugger point that the issue is when I type `firebase` in my useTasks and useEffects. I have already referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636255/firebase-firestore-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-initialize-cloud-firestore) and tried adjusting the imports, but that didn't work either.

Here is the code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import { firebase } from '../firebase';


import { collatedTasksExist } from '../helpers';


export const useTasks = selectedProject => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [archivedTasks, setArchivedTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('tasks')
      .where('userId', '==', 'nfeCumoN');

    unsubscribe =
      selectedProject && !collatedTasksExist(selectedProject)
        ? (unsubscribe = unsubscribe.where('projectId', '==', selectedProject))
        : selectedProject === 'TODAY'
        ? (unsubscribe = unsubscribe.where(
            'date',
            '==',
            moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY')
          ))
        : selectedProject === 'INBOX' || selectedProject === 0
        ? (unsubscribe = unsubscribe.where('date', '==', ''))
        : unsubscribe;

    unsubscribe = unsubscribe.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      const newTasks = snapshot.docs.map(task => ({
        id: task.id,
        ...task.data(),
      }));

      setTasks(
        selectedProject === 'NEXT_7'
          ? newTasks.filter(
              task =>
                moment(task.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').diff(moment(), 'days') <= 7 &&
                task.archived !== true
            )
          : newTasks.filter(task => task.archived !== true)
      );
      setArchivedTasks(newTasks.filter(task => task.archived !== false));
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [selectedProject]);

  return { tasks, archivedTasks };
};

export const useProjects = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('projects')
      .where('userId', '==', 'nfeCumoN')
      .orderBy('projectId')
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        const allProjects = snapshot.docs.map(project => ({
          ...project.data(),
          docId: project.id,
        }));

        if (JSON.stringify(allProjects) !== JSON.stringify(projects)) {
          setProjects(allProjects);
        }
      });
  }, [projects]);

  return { projects, setProjects };
};
```

and here is my firebase.js file (back one directory)

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';




const firebaseConfig = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBic0yipL6n63-ch_bj4evvM0XVcLCkqr4",
    authDomain: "matt-task-manager.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://matt-task-manager.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "matt-task-manager",
    storageBucket: "matt-task-manager.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "728902353168",
    appId: "1:728902353168:web:38283d15434152f168a595",
    measurementId: "G-PXPFLK2R8X",
    
});

export { firebaseConfig as firebase};
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you are getting an error, you should copy that exact text into the question, and also explain which line of code causes it.  Please edit the question to provide these debugging details.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've edited to include the specific code that causes the error. It is when I call `firebase`

Comment: You probably don't want to share your full configuration to the internet like this before you publish your app.  That's a potential security problem if you don't have your security rules set up yet.

Answer (score 0):

try import this, hope it works!

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
//or both
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/functions';
```