# Firebase works fine in Web App but it's giving me the error while I try to run it on Android

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native

When I try to Register a new user in the Firebase app ran on Browser(Web App) is working fine, with no errors whatsoever.

[image]

But When I tried to do the same on an Android device, it is showing the following error:

```
_firebase.default.firestore is not a function. (In '_firebase.default.firestore()', '_firebase.default.firestore' is undefined)
- node_modules\@react-navigation\stack\src\views\Header\HeaderContainer.tsx:87:10 in scenes.slice.map$argument_0
* http://192.168.43.29:19001/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:138158:26 in <unknown>
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:19:290 in <anonymous>
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:19:222 in <anonymous>
* http://192.168.43.29:19001/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:138235:10 in Zb
- node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\auth.js:13:433 in Ja
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 
in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in 
__callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in 
__guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in 
flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

When I looked at the project explorer, I noticed that there are a bunch of errors in `node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\Data\LogBoxData.js`, they only show up when I try to register a user from an Android device.

[image]

When I checked the firebase console, users are being created from Android device as well as Web App ran in the browser.

Code is kind of big, so as to avoid confusing code dump I have set up the Expo Snack reproducing the same result.

Here is the link: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/react-native-firebase-issue)

I have already tried going through a similar question: [firebase.firestore() is not a function when trying to initialize Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636255/firebase-firestore-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-initialize-cloud-firestore)

But it's not working.

[UPDATE: Now it's working after restarting the project, the above question's solution did work]

Comment: can you try importing `import '@firebase/firestore'` to `register.js`

Comment: is it working post `firestore` import??

Comment: on the browser, yes. But Android is still giving the same error.