# Firebase.firestore() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are trying to convert this json object timestamp:

```
Object {
  "_nanoseconds": 725000000,
  "_seconds": 1621386976,
}
```

to a firebase timestamp:

```
t {
  "nanoseconds": 725000000,
  "seconds": 1621386976,
}
```

Our code where the error is being thrown:

```
const lastItemIndex = thoughts.length - 1;
console.log(thoughts[lastItemIndex].date_created); // <--- logs Object timestamp

const seconds = thoughts[lastItemIndex].date_created._seconds;
console.log(seconds); // <--- logs seconds

const nanoseconds = thoughts[lastItemIndex].date_created._nanoseconds;
console.log(nanoseconds); // <---- logs nanoseconds

const lastDate = Firebase.firestore().Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds); // <--- error
console.log(lastDate);
```

We are importing Firebase in our file like so:

```
import Firebase from '../../firebase';
```

And within the firebase.js file:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

// Optionally import the services that you want to use
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

The warning we get:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _firebase.default.firestore().Timestamp is not a function. (In '_firebase.default.firestore().Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds)', '_firebase.default.firestore().Timestamp' is undefined)]
```

We have also tried the following:

```
const lastDate = new Firebase.firestore.Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds);
```

and get the following error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _firebase.default.firestore.Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds)')]
```

We are following the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) to no avail. How can we convert this correctly?

**Edit**

exporting both Time_stamp and Firebase breaks the app [ the rest of the app does not recognize the Firebase export ]

`export default Firebase` makes everything back to normal. But the issue of converting the timestamp still remains

```
// Initialize Firebase

export const Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const Time_stamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp();

// export default Firebase;
```

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50684682/5589405

Comment: @fortunee yep, I have been doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in how you are importing & exporting the library.

#### Reviewing your code

If this is where you are importing from the main library, you also need to make sure you are exporting it correctly. Looking at your current `firebase.js` file:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

// Optionally import the services that you want to use
import 'firebase/firestore';

/* ... */

// Initialize Firebase

const Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default Firebase; // <- this is a firebase.app.App not firebase itself
```

You are exporting an instance of [`firebase.app.App`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App) instead of `firebase` (the whole firebase library & namespace).

When you have an [`firebase.app.App`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App) instance, you can access Firestore **of that app** using [`app.firestore()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App#firestore). Because you import this app instance as `Firebase` in your main code, you confuse this with the normal [`firebase.firestore()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore) which does something else.

To help illustrate the difference, take a look at this:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";

const config = { /* ... */ };

const defaultFirebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);

// the instance of Firestore for the default app
const dbApp = defaultFirebaseApp.firestore();

// the instance of Firestore for the default app
const dbDefault = firebase.firestore();
// OR
// const dbDefault = firebase.firestore(dbApp);

console.log(dbApp === dbDefault); // -> true

const namedFirebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config, "something");

const dbNamedApp = namedFirebaseApp.firestore(); // returns instance of Firestore for the named app
// OR
// const dbNamedApp = firebase.firestore(dbNamedApp);

console.log(dbDefault === dbNamedApp); // -> false
```

#### Recommended export style

To properly export the Firebase library from `firebase.js`, you need to (and should)  be using:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

/* ... */

// Initialize Firebase

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase; // re-export firebase library & namespace
```

By re-exporting the library this way, you can use it in the same way as all the code samples you encounter:

```
import firebase from '../../firebase';

const {_nanoseconds, _seconds} = thoughts[lastItemIndex].date_created;
const dateCreatedAsTimestamp = new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(_nanoseconds, _seconds);

const db = firebase.firestore();

db.doc("collection/doc")
  .set({
    date_created: dateCreatedAsTimestamp
  })
  .then(
    () => console.log("success"),
    (err) => console.error("failed", err);
  );
```

#### Alternative export style

If you intend to add some utility functions to `firebase.js`, the way you import stuff changes slightly

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

/* ... */

// Initialize Firebase

export const defaultApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export function castToTimestamp(timestampLikeObject) {
  const {_nanoseconds, _seconds} = timestampLikeObject;
  return new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(_nanoseconds, _seconds);
}

export default firebase; // re-export firebase library & namespace as the default
```

With the above file, you would instead import it as:

```
// you can import this normally like in the other example, but we'll
// include some of the other exports (like the utility function)
import firebase, { castToTimestamp } from '../../firebase';

const {_nanoseconds, _seconds} = thoughts[lastItemIndex].date_created;
const dateCreatedAsTimestamp = new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(_nanoseconds, _seconds);
// OR
// const dateCreatedAsTimestamp = castToTimestamp(thoughts[lastItemIndex].date_created);

const db = firebase.firestore();

db.doc("collection/doc")
  .set({
    date_created: dateCreatedAsTimestamp
  })
  .then(
    () => console.log("success"),
    (err) => console.error("failed", err);
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
export const timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
let bob = new timestamp();
console.log("bob, bob);
```

NOTE:

firebase.firestore.Timestamp()

**NOT**

firebase.firestore().Timestamp()

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

Comment: It's part of the namespace, not a method of firestore().

Comment: I assume that I have to export this from my firebase.js file, where I initialize firebase. Before adding the timestamp export, I was exporting firebase like so: export default Firebase; - With the addition of the timestamp export, I have to export both. But when I export both, firebase does not work in the rest of the app. [perhaps it is not being exported correctly?] I export both like this: export const Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(...) export const Time_stamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;

Comment: added clarifying code in my original post. when I export just firebase [export default Firebase] everything works. When I export both firebase and timestamp, the app breaks.

Comment: It's the difference between a NAMED export and a DEFAULT export.  There can be only ONE default export, and unlimited NAMED exports:
```
export const timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
export default Firebase;
```
```
import Firebase, { timestamp } from "/whatever/firebase";
```